# What's Selenoid video filename

Tags: selenoid

Example - selenoid7a408b66263ee21c5e896514aa938105.mp4
Is there a way to know what name of the file is going to be - to log it for users? (it's not browser session id)
Is there a way to give this file a name that I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenoid video file name by default is `<session-id>.mp4`. What you are showing is temporary file name which is renamed to correct one when browser session is stopped. You can update video file name using `videoName` capability. https://aerokube.com/selenoid/latest/#_video_recording_enablevideo_videoname_videoscreensize_videoframerate_videocodec